# how to make multi charts for Plotly Gauge chart?

Tags: python, python-2.7, plotly

I am following this direction(tutorial) to make plotly gauge chart

(https://plot.ly/python/gauge-charts/).

But it seems that it would only create one chart on the screen.

Do you know how to make multi charts that include those gauge charts in one screen(in one html file)?

So I want to create many gauges in one screen.

Thanks a lot!

So this is the code.

```
import plotly
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

from plotly.offline import plot


import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

base_chart = {
    "values": [40, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
    "labels": ["-", "0", "20", "40", "60", "80", "100"],
    "domain": {"x": [0, .48]},
    "marker": {
        "colors": [
            'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
        ],
        "line": {
            "width": 1
        }
    },
    "name": "Gauge",
    "hole": .4,
    "type": "pie",
    "direction": "clockwise",
    "rotation": 108,
    "showlegend": False,
    "hoverinfo": "none",
    "textinfo": "label",
    "textposition": "outside"
}


meter_chart = {
    "values": [50, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
    "labels": ["Days" + "<br>" + "haaga", "How", "Many", "Days", "Are", "Left"],
    "marker": {
        'colors': [
            'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            'rgb(226,126,64)',
            'rgb(223,162,103)',
            'rgb(223,189,139)',
            'rgb(226,210,172)',
            'rgb(232,226,202)'

        ]
    },
    "domain": {"x": [0, 0.48]},
    "name": "Days Guage",
    "hole": .3,
    "type": "pie",
    "direction": "clockwise",
    "rotation": 90,
    "showlegend": False,
    "textinfo": "label",
    "textposition": "inside",
    "hoverinfo": "none",


}


layout = {
    'xaxis': {
        'showticklabels': False,
        'showgrid': False,
        'zeroline': False,
    },
    'yaxis': {
        'showticklabels': False,
        'showgrid': False,
        'zeroline': False,
    },
    'shapes': [
        {
            'type': 'path',
            'path': 'M 0.235 0.5 L 0.24 0.65 L 0.245 0.5 Z',
            'fillcolor': 'rgba(44, 160, 101, 0.5)',
            'line': {
                'width': 0.5
            },
            'xref': 'paper',
            'yref': 'paper'
        }
    ],
    'annotations': [
        {
            'xref': 'paper',
            'yref': 'paper',
            'x': 0.23,
            'y': 0.45,
            'text': '50',
            'showarrow': False
        }
    ]
}

# we don't want the boundary now
base_chart['marker']['line']['width'] = 0

fig = {"data": [base_chart, meter_chart],
       "layout": layout}
plot(fig, filename='gauge-meter-chart')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that tick is generated as a `shape` object under layout, this can be achieved easily with some  minor calcuations for `x` and `y` positions. Please refer the below example where I use a `for loop` to define the number of columns and place the shapes and annotations in the correct positions.

**Note: I have done this only for columns, please apply the logic and make it work for rows also, also please post your solution if you do, so that people can refer it, in the future!!**

Please try out the below code and let me know if your issue is resolved!

```
import plotly
import plotly.plotly  as py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.offline as py_offline
import plotly.graph_objs as go
py_offline.init_notebook_mode()

base_chart = {
    "values": [40, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
    "labels": ["-", "0", "20", "40", "60", "80", "100"],
    "domain": {"x": [0, .48]},
    "marker": {
        "colors": [
            'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
        ],
        "line": {
            "width": 1
        }
    },
    "name": "Gauge",
    "hole": .4,
    "type": "pie",
    "direction": "clockwise",
    "rotation": 108,
    "showlegend": False,
    "hoverinfo": "none",
    "textinfo": "label",
    "textposition": "outside"
}


meter_chart = {
    "values": [50, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
    "labels": ["Days" + "<br>" + "haaga", "How", "Many", "Days", "Are", "Left"],
    "marker": {
        'colors': [
            'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            'rgb(226,126,64)',
            'rgb(223,162,103)',
            'rgb(223,189,139)',
            'rgb(226,210,172)',
            'rgb(232,226,202)'

        ]
    },
    "domain": {"x": [0, 0.48]},
    "name": "Days Guage",
    "hole": .3,
    "type": "pie",
    "direction": "clockwise",
    "rotation": 90,
    "showlegend": False,
    "textinfo": "label",
    "textposition": "inside",
    "hoverinfo": "none",


}


layout = {
    'xaxis': {
        'showticklabels': False,
        'showgrid': False,
        'zeroline': False
    },
    'yaxis': {
        'showticklabels': False,
        'showgrid': False,
        'zeroline': False
    },
    'shapes': [],
    'annotations': []
}
base_shape = {
                'type': 'path',
                'path': 'M 0.49 0.5 L 0.5 0.65 L 0.51 0.5 Z',
                'fillcolor': 'rgba(44, 160, 101, 0.5)',
                'line': {
                    'width': 0.5
                },
                'xref': 'paper',
                'yref': 'paper'
            }

base_annotation = {
                        'xref': 'paper',
                        'yref': 'paper',
                        'x': 0,
                        'y': 0.45,
                        'text': '50',
                        'showarrow': False
                    }

arr = []
columns = 4
tick_width = 0.009
increment = 1/columns
initial = 0
for i in range(columns):
    basechart = copy.deepcopy(base_chart)
    meterchart = copy.deepcopy(meter_chart)
    start = initial
    end = initial + increment
    basechart['domain']['x'] = [start, end]
    meterchart['domain']['x'] = [start, end]
    # code for placing the tick on each of the dials
    shape = copy.deepcopy(base_shape)
    temp = (start + (increment/2))
    shape['path'] = 'M '+str(temp-tick_width/2)+' 0.5 L '+str(temp)+' 0.59 L '+str(temp+tick_width/2)+' 0.5 Z'
    layout['shapes'].append(shape)
    # code for placing the value annotation on each of the dials
    annotation = copy.deepcopy(base_annotation)
    annotation['x'] = temp
    layout['annotations'].append(annotation)
    arr.append(basechart)
    arr.append(meterchart)
    initial = end

# we don't want the boundary now
base_chart['marker']['line']['width'] = 0

fig = {"data": arr,
       "layout": layout}
py_offline.iplot(fig, filename='gauge-meter-chart')
```